# express server and socketio WITH typescript :) ==> 'server' does not exist on type 'App'

Tags: express, typescript, socket.io

I'm trying this classic implementation of an expressjs server with socketio:

```
    this.app = express();
    this.server = http.createServer(this.app);
    this.io = socket(this.server);
```

But typescript throw those errors :

```
src/server/ts/app.ts(23,38): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Application' is not assignable to parameter of type '(request: IncomingMessage, response: ServerResponse) => void'.
src/server/ts/app.ts(24,8): error TS2339: Property 'io' does not exist on type 'App'.
src/server/ts/app.ts(24,25): error TS2339: Property 'server' does not exist on type 'App'.
```

How should I manage this ? What is the right way to handle this ?

Comment: I noticed that there is a downvote without a reason. Did my usage not work for you?

Comment: well this is not related to typescript

Comment: Oh, I see.  You are trying to compile your app.js from typescript. I have never seen anybody try to transpile the express server. my apologies

At the top of the page try 

var io: any;

and possibly repeat for ur other missing variables

Answer (score 1):

this is my workaround

somewhere in controller:

```
(req.app as any).io as io.Server
```

Answer (score -2):

it seems like your other question was posted after this, is this still relevant?

ok lets see what ive done that worked. I have seperated my sockets into a config file because my app.js was getting cluttered.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/')));

  var clients = {};

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io  = require('socket.io')(server);

require('./config/app.socket.js')(io);
server.listen(8001);
io.set("origins", "*:*");
```

So, I cut out the middleman and pass the server directly to the socket.io import. then, I pass the reference to that io server to my app.socket.js file and listen to the server on port 8001

Here is my app.socket.js initialization

```
module.exports = function(io){
  var clients = {};

   var sockets;

  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  sockets = socket;

  socket.on(//your socket function)

}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't help at all. The original question was regarding Typescript.

Comment: I remember there being a reason i posted this here in regards to another post he made previously but I agree. Im not sure why i posted this.